# Medibuntu 'Bad Gateway' Connection Failure

Tags: 12.04, dvd, medibuntu, surface

I'm attempting to make DVDs playable using the community docs suggested command `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`. This consistently returns the following failure:

```
--2013-07-14 15:29:38--  http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/precise/free/binary-amd64/Packages
Resolving packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)... 88.191.101.8
Connecting to packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)|88.191.101.8|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 502 Bad Gateway
2013-07-14 15:30:00 ERROR 502: Bad Gateway.

Dynamic fetch failed; Falling back to static fetch
--2013-07-14 15:30:00--  http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/free/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.2.10-0.2medibuntu1_amd64.deb
Resolving packages.medibuntu.org (packages.medibuntu.org)... 88.191.101.8
Connecting to packages.medibuntu.org     (packages.medibuntu.org)|88.191.101.8|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 502 Bad Gateway
2013-07-14 15:30:23 ERROR 502: Bad Gateway.
```

I took this to mean the Medibuntu server might be down. This suspicion was deepened when, in attempting to visit medibuntu.org using Firefox, the page would not load, instead displaying this message:

**Response Error.**

**Technical description:
502 Bad Gateway - Response Error, a bad response was received from another proxy server or the destination origin server.**

This also remained the same as I checked back periodically over the past two weeks. I have no problems surfing the rest of the web.

But today I discovered that, if I check medibuntu.org with my android phone's Firefox, the page loads fine. Yet I still cannot load it on my Ubuntu Netbook.

I'm providing this information in case it might shed light on what is going on. My only concern right now is with being able to download the encryption library and watch DVDs.

Comment: How does your ubuntu box react to any site? eg. `wget http://askubuntu.com/`? what do you get from `host www.medibuntu.org`?

Answer (score 1):

First, read [Here](https://launchpad.net/medibuntu/) of what medibuntu is.

Then follow the sources.list.d/ way. Execute the following command in terminal.

```
 sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

Read the [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu) from more info.

**UPDATE:**

Maybe this announcement is related to your problem https://launchpad.net/medibuntu/+announcement/11219

Also a discussion is already open on [test.ubuntu-discourse.org](http://test.ubuntu-discourse.org/t/is-losing-medibuntu-support-going-to-cause-people-issues/222)

Comment: That command returned a Bad Gateway error as well.

Comment: Try another mirror. Replace the `http://packages.medibuntu.org/` with the URL of another server. See the list [here](http://www.medibuntu.org/repository.php)

Comment: This command resembles old joke about simplicity in Gentoo installation process :)